# geocoder.geocode( { 'address': query}, function callback(results, status) { not calling from jquery

Tags: jquery, methods, call, google-geocoder

i am running to problem as   geocoder.geocode(
             {'address': address`enter code here` }, method is not executing and skipping to next method,
following is my method.

Please help me out,i am struggling from last two days but no output, its not throwing any error,but  geocoder.geocode()`enter code here` not executing ,simply skipping it

```
function VerifyLocation() {
    $('#verify').click(function () {
    alert("verification");
        $('#verifyLocationVerify').hide();
        var address=$("#address").val();
        var sutenumber=$("#sutenumber").val();
        var city=$("#city").val();
        var country=$("#country option:selected").text();
        var state=$("#state option:selected").text();
        var pincode=$("#pincode").val();
        var addressdata=address+","+sutenumber+","+city+","+state+","+country+","+pincode;
         geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
         geocoder.geocode(
         {'address': addressdata },
        function(data, status) { 
        if(data.length==0)
        {
                alert("location not found");
                $('#verifyLocationVerify').show();
                $('#verifyLocationConfirm').hide();
                $('#verifyLocationVerifySuccess').hide();
            }
            else{
            glat=data[0].geometry.location.nb;
            glng=data[0].geometry.location.ob;
                setCookie("latitude1",glat);
                setCookie("langitude1",glng);
                var styles = [{
                    "featureType": "road",
                    "stylers": [
                    { "lightness": 40 },
                    { "saturation": -100 }
                    ]
                }];
            var styledMap = new google.maps.StyledMapType(styles, { name: "Styled Map" });
            var latlang = new google.maps.LatLng(glat, glng);
            var mapOptions = {
                zoom: 15,
                center: latlang,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
                };
            map =  new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("new_location"), mapOptions);
            map.mapTypes.set('map_style', styledMap);
            map.setMapTypeId('map_style');
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: latlang,
                map: map,
                title: 'Entered Address Location'
            });
            }
        });

        $('#verifyLocationConfirm').show(function () {
            $('#verifyNo').click(function () {
                $('#verifyLocationVerify').show();
                $('#verifyLocationConfirm').hide();
                $('#verifyLocationVerifySuccess').hide();

                setCookie("verificationstatus","no");
            });

            $('#verifyYes').click(function () {
                //$('#verifyLocation').empty().removeClass('secondary').addClass('success').html('<p>Your Location has been Verified</p>');
                //$('#saveNew , #saveCont').removeClass('disabled');
                $('#verifyLocationVerify').hide();
                $('#verifyLocationConfirm').hide();
                $('#verifyLocationVerifySuccess').show();
                setCookie("verificationstatus","yes");
            });

        });
    });
}
```

Thanks & Regards,
Sathish Gai

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how old this question is, but I firstly, I see that you do not have a call to

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=$GoogleAPIKey&sensor=false"></script>
```

but I have it and I'm also not getting the call back to happen. So IDK.